# How to match a string in URI with regular expression?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, regex

In my Apache config httpd.conf, I wish to setup a rule like below

```
SetEnvIfNoCase %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(getBook+)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

I am hoping to do no-gzip when my URL looks like

```
http://myurl.fake.com/book/getBook3?id=234 
http://myurl.fake.com/book/getBook1?id=xxx
```

I am not sure if I can do that by setting up something like the above in httpd.conf..

The reason I do query string is because the url 
`myurl.fake.com/book/getBook3` was mod_rewrite from 
`myurl.fake.com/index.php?controller=book&action=getBook3`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The following rewrite rule below the first rewrite rule should do the trick:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=[0-9]*$
RewriteRule ^(/book/getBook(1|3))$ $1 [E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1,QSA]
```

Make sure your first rewrite rule for myurl.fake.com/index.php?controller=book&action=getBook3 does not have the 'L' flag